# Why does using sudo run a different version?

Tags: software-installation, cmake

First I installed the version of cmake from the repos:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

Then I discovered that I need feature of cmake that is not in the older version, so I unstalled cmake:

```
sudo apt-get remove cmake
```

And installed from source:

```
wget http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.3/cmake-3.3.2.tar.gz
tar -xzf cmake-3.3.2.tar.gz
cd cmake-3.3.2/
./configure 
make
sudo make install
```

Now, running `sudo cmake .` correctly generates a makefile.

But running `cmake .` genereates an error:

`bash: /usr/bin/cmake: No such file or directory`

reinstalling the repository version and comparing the output of:

```
cmake --version
sudo cmake --version
```

indicates that the from-source version is being run when `sudo` is invoked, and the repository version is being run when it is not.

What is going on here?

I checked that `$PATH` includes `/usr/local/bin` *before* `/usr/bin`, but I'm not sure where else to look.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `sudo $SHELL -c 'whoami; command -v cmake'` and the output of `command -v cmake`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` keeps a hash table of recently executed files and their location, so it doesn't need to search `PATH` every time a command is invoked.

You can see the currently kept hashes with `hash`. Look for `cmake` in there. To clear the hash table and make `bash` search `PATH` anew, do

```
hash -r
```

See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86012/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-hash-command) wonderful explanation.

Comment: I wish I had run `hash` *before* running `hash -r` so I could try and make a guess about how it got messed up.  Instead I just ran `hash -r` and found that things were working properly after that.  Thanks for the help.